# Warning message - dummy from dummies package

Tags: r, dummy-variable, contrast, model.matrix

I am using the dummies package to generate dummy variables for  categorical variables, some  with more than two categories.

```
testdf<- data.frame(
  "A" = as.factor(c(1,2,2,3,3,1)),
  "B" = c('A','B','A','B','C','C'),
  "C"= c('D','D','E','D','D','E'))
#
#Generate dummy variables:
#
testdf<- cbind(testdf, dummy(testdf$C, sep='_'))
testdf<- cbind(testdf, dummy(testdf$B, sep='_'))
```

For both commands I get:

> ```
> Warning message:
> In model.matrix.default(~x - 1, model.frame(~x - 1), contrasts = FALSE) :
>   non-list contrasts argument ignored
> ```

The results seem correct though. Can you please advice regarding the reason of the warning?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the code for `dummy`, the function calls

```
mm <- model.matrix(~x - 1, model.frame(~x - 1), contrasts = FALSE)
```

Note they are passing "FALSE" to the `contrasts=` arguments (which is really the `contrasts.arg=` argument). According to the `?model.matrix` help page, this is supposed to be a list of contrasts. It's not supposed to be a TRUE/FALSE value. Note this additional message in the help page `?model.matrix`

> Whereas invalid contrasts.args have been ignored always, they are warned about since R version 3.6.0

So basically the package used a parameter incorrectly that was silently ignored in previous version of R, but starting in R 3.6 now triggers a warning. The behavior isn't any different, but the warning is new. It doesn't look like that package has been updated since 2012 so it might not ever get updated to make the warning go away.

Comment: That is a pretty detailed answer, thank you for your kind attention. It is a good reminder that packages and programs are not perfect and keep evolving, I will keep an eye on if they are still maintained from now on.